# Group by Linq . Count of Key field

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
select    
  count(di.field1) as myCount,
  di.field2
  from di
group by  di.field2
```

Im trying to understand the concept of this :

```
 group di.field2 by new { di.field1, di.field2 } into g
       select new
          {
             documentID = g.Key.field2,
             docCount = g.Count(????)
          });
```

How do i get the value of the field1 count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
group di by di.field2 into g
       select new
          {
             documentID = g.Key,
             docCount = g.Select(c => c.field1).Count()
          });
```

Comment: Nope ... i don't have access to any of my proprieties within the count

Comment: really? well i do, but never the less it was wrong. I updated the answer

Comment: please post the code that initialize `di` perhaps that is the source of the problem

Comment: I needed to select my entire di item. Damn .. working at this hour has its drawbacks. Thanks sir .. u deserve a cookie !

Answer (score 1):

```
    from p in di
    group p by p.field2 into g 
    select new { field2 = g.Key, field2Count = g.Count() };
```

Check this., This should work

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do the grouping to get the field count?  Can't you just do:

```
var count=di.field1.Count;
```

Comment: Nope ... i need the number of field1 encounters that have the same field2